# Context action in Xamarin Forms ListView stops working

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, menuitem

I have created an app in Xamarin Forms targeting iOS.
In two of my ListViews I have created context actions using MenuItems.

Problem:
**If I swype open the MenuItem and press the "Back" button, of my Xamarin Forms page (while the MenuItem is open), all the context actions stops working.**
The swype functionality will not work for any of the Listviews.
I have to completely close the App to get the context actions (swype) to work again.

I tested the example project for the ListView and it has the same problem
[ListView sample project from Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/ListView/interactivity/)

I use the latest version of Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Xamarin Forms.
You can follow the progress [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58875).

Answer (score 0):

you have to **refresh** the **Listview** once again when you click back or again you enter into list view page.

I had a exact scenario like this in mine and this how i solved it.

Comment: No event is triggered by the back button....I have made a "dirty solution" by adding the code to OnDisappearing(). But I don't like this solution, seems like a bug in the ListView component.

Comment: btw its just not clear what you need here, can you post your code or samples here please